# Move Raw file to SD card in Android

Tags: android, file-io

I have a method that will `copy an Audio file from raw folder to SD card`. It takes two inputs

- ressound: .ogg Audio Raw file id.
- fName: the file name of the raw file in the SD card.

**Updated**

```
     public boolean saveas(int ressound, String fName){  
     byte[] buffer=null;  
     InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);  
     int size=0;  

     try {  
      size = fIn.available();  
      buffer = new byte[size];  
      fIn.read(buffer);  
      fIn.close();  
     } catch (IOException e) {  
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
      return false;  
     }  

     String path="/sdcard/music/[my_package_name]/"; 
     String filename=fName+".ogg";
     String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
     String completePath = baseDir + File.separator + "music" + File.separator + "my_package" + File.separator + filename;


     boolean exists = (new File(completePath)).exists();  
     if (!exists){new File(completePath).mkdirs();}  

     FileOutputStream save;  
     try {  
      save = new FileOutputStream(completePath);  
      save.write(buffer);  
      save.flush();  
      save.close();  
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
      return false;
     } catch (IOException e) {  
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
      return false;  
     }      

     sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));  

     File k = new File(path, filename);  

     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());  
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "exampletitle");  
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");  
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "cssounds ");  
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);  
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);  
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);  
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);  

     //Insert it into the database  
     this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);  

     return true;  
    }
```

If the method returns true, Then the file is saved correctly to SD card. If it returns false, then there is an error. In my case, The method returns false when it enters the `FileNotFoundException` block. I can't find why !! everything seems fine to me.

In case you ask me if I add the WRITE permission, I added it to the application tag in the Manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Consider using `File f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` for getting SD Card directory in device independed way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has nothing to do with the code. It is a **permission-related** thing. I added the permission inside the `application tag`. It must be outside it. It must be in the `root tag`.

Wired for me because it make sense to put it in the `application tag` not the `Manifest tag` !

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 2):

Use this for path:

```
string baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
string path = baseDir + File.Separator + "music" + File.Separator + "yourpackagename" + filename;
```

Comment: So ? What are you suggesting ?

Comment: Intially make `path = path + filename;` so you can declare`save =  new FileOutputStream(path);`

Comment: Yes as this one. Nothing changed

Comment: It seems that `mkdirs()` returns **false** always. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you missed a `File.separator` between the package and the filename. I added it. However, the same error appears !

Comment: LISTEN this is getting very ! just please edit your code up.. show me all the code now.. with `getExternalStorageDirectory`

Answer (score 0):

Please don't hardcode paths. Use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) to get the path of a large storage medium. Some phones mount sdcards in /mnt/sdcard or somewhere else, some just don't have one and rely on inbuilt flash.

This might throw the error, but I don't think is the error in this case since you are probably testing with your phone/emulator, where this path applies.